# Как вернуть данные от php после ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Как вывести результат ajax запроса в alert?

Есть ajax запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#singup').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: this.method,
      url: this.action,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      };
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Вы успешно зарегестрированны!");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Есть php:

```
<?php
require "db.php"; 

$data = $_POST;
$errors = array();

if (R::count('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login'])) > 0 ) {
  $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином уже существует!';
}
if (R::count('users', 'email = ?', array($data['email'])) > 0 ) {
  $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким email уже существует!';
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->surname = $data['surname'];
    $user->login = $data['login'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $user->start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    R::store($user);
}
else{
  echo array_shift($errors);
}
?>
```

Перечитал множество вопросов на эту тему, везде говорят сделать именно так в js:

```
success: function(data) {
  alert(data);
};
```

В php:

```
echo array_shift($errors);
```

Но в итоге, вместо вывода в alert, вывод происходит как echo в php файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем скрипте синтаксическая ошибка (посмотрите сообщение в консоли браузера), поэтому страница ведет себя, как если бы этого скрипта вообще не было.

Уберите точку с запятой после:

```
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  };
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#singup').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: this.method,
      url: this.action,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      };
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Вы успешно зарегестрированны!");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Точно, я и внимание на это не обращал так как данные в базу заносились ) Спасибо